# Converting Sprite based SWF file to mxml

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I wrote a big Actionscript project using AS3 as an "Actionscript Project" in Flash Builder 4.5.  I have a bunch of solid, reusable, code, but one of the big components is a main.as file that extends Sprite and serves as the display code for my application.

I now, for various reasons, need that to be a Flex application.  I'm trying to get the most minimal wrapper possible, so here's what I have (thanks to the internet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="590" minHeight="700"
           initialize="initPlayer()">`

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.core.UIComponent;
        public function initPlayer():void {
            Alert.show("Testing!");
            var comp:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
            comp.addChild(new MainView());
            addChild(comp);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

when I launch this, however, it comes up with a blank window.  No errors, the alert doesn't fire, nothing.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `applicationComplete` instead of `initialize`. initialize is triggered early in the application life cycle, and stuff like doing `addChild` is better suited later on in the cycle (`applicationComplete` corresponds to `creationComplete` in sub components).

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple sprite class "TestSprite" instead your "MainView". It works. Both the alert  ahd the TestSprite works. so, i think there must be something in your "MainView" prevent flex display it.

```
public class TestSprite extends Sprite
{
    public function TestSprite()
    {
        super();
        graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```